# snmp on devices via ssh

Tags: java, ssh, snmp, snmp4j

I have a device in network. I would like to use SNMP to get information. Is it possible for using SSH and then SNMP for messages over ssh session ? I am using Java for implementation.
It seems snmp4j is not yet ready for the snmp via ssh.

Can you please give me some example, if its possible ?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you should write your application software developers and ask them to support [RFC5592](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5592), which is the standard for how to do "SNMP over SSH".  Not every stack has support for it yet, but some do (like the most recent version of [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/)).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, SNMP runs over UDP; the SNMP implementations I know cannot directly use SSH.

However, you can tunnel UDP over SSH, and thus tunnel SNMP traffic.

One possibility is to tunnel using [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

See e.g. 
http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.security.ssh/2007-01/msg00136.html
for an explanation.

You could probably also configure SNMP to run over TCP instead of UDP, which makes tunneling easier.